# Uncaught ReferenceError: Couldn't call an ajax function inside html form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The function named post1() is being called in the html form tag. This code is throwing an error which is "Uncaught ReferenceError: post1 is not defined". How to call the function inside the HTML code?
Tia.

```
<script>
function post1()
{
var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
if(comment && name)
{
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "post_cmnt.php",
    data: 
    {
      user_comm:comment,
    user_name:name
    },
    success: function (response) 
    {
    document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML=response+document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("comment").value="";
      document.getElementById("username").value="";

    }
  });
}

return false;
 }
</script>
<form method='POST' action="#" onsubmit="return post1();">
```

Comment: Hi, put that whole `<script></script>` tag before `</body>` tag

Comment: @Swati I tried doing this! But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {})` this would initialize your javascript code on load.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function post1() {
      var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
      var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
      if (comment && name) {
        $.ajax
          ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "post_cmnt.php",
            data:
            {
              user_comm: comment,
              user_name: name
            },
            success: function (response) {
              document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML;
              document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
              document.getElementById("username").value = "";

            }
          });
      }

      return false;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it isn't working. When I add the script tag before the </body> tag, the output page is blank.

Comment: You can try
```
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the page is not getting fully loaded.